# Keyboard response VERY slowly when debugging TypeScript in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, typescript

I have created a simple TypeScript project in Visual Studio and I'm using VS to debug it in Internet Explorer.

I can set breakpoints, modify code, add/remove files without problems before starting debugging, but when the debugger is running the Keyboard responds INCREDIBLY slowly - on the order of 4-5 seconds to type a single character.  Even pressing a shortcut key won't respond for a long time, and this extends to everything in the OS.  However, the UI does not hang, and I can still interact with the mouse without any delay.

Stopping debugging resolves the issue almost instantly.

Example: If I press F9 to enable or disable a breakpoint, I can then enable and disable it manually with the mouse (by clicking in the margin) multiple times instantly.  Then after I stop, eventually the F9 will be received and the breakpoint will toggle again.

Example: Open Notepad, type a word with no problems.  Start debugging, switch back to notepad, and hit 3 characters wait 5 seconds for each character to appear.

Any thoughts?  Is there some configuration in VS I need to check.  Something about my IE configuration that's causing problems?  I couldn't get debugging working with Chrome through Visual Studio so I can't confirm if that experiences the same issue.

Comment: Do you have IntelliTrace and/or CodeLens turned on in Visual Studio? I've noticed that these slow down debugging when I have them turned on.

Comment: CodeLens should have an impact regardless of whether or not I'm debugging, so it' not likely that.  And since this is a TypeScript project it's unlikey that Intellitrace is running.  Also, it's causing issues outside of VS as well as inside.